# @RefreshScope causes "object is not an instance of declaring class". Why?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

This works:

```java
@Configuration
public class RouteLocatorConfig {
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorProvider routeLocatorProvider) {
        return routeLocatorProvider.getRouteLocator();
    }
}
```

but this doesn't:

```java
@Configuration
public class RouteLocatorConfig {
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorProvider routeLocatorProvider) {
        return routeLocatorProvider.getRouteLocator();
    }
}
```

`RouteLocatorProvider` is a class that I wrote myself. It's annotated as a `@Component` and is scanned by another `@Configuration` called `WebClientConfig`. Let's ignore for a moment that it's semantically questionable

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "by.afinny.apigateway")
public class WebClientConfig {
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class RouteLocatorProvider {
    private final EurekaClient eurekaClient;
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    private final RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder;
    private final OpenAPIV3Parser apiParser;
    @Getter
    private RouteLocator routeLocator;

    public RouteLocatorProvider(EurekaClient eurekaClient, WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
                                RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        this.eurekaClient = eurekaClient;
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
        this.routeLocatorBuilder = routeLocatorBuilder;
        this.apiParser = new OpenAPIV3Parser();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListener() {
        eurekaClient.registerEventListener(event -> {
            if (event instanceof CacheRefreshedEvent) { // wtf, spring
                refreshRoutings();
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshRoutings() {
        List<Application> applications = findOtherRegisteredApplications();
        Map<Application, SwaggerParseResult> docs = mapToDocs(applications);
        routeLocator = buildRouteLocatorFrom(docs);
        // initially, I called refreshScope.refresh(RouteLocator.class) here but then removed it to isolate the cause – removing it didn't help
    }

// more logic
```

You may be wondering what all those methods do. But it really doesn't matter. If you implement them like this (just to make the compiler happy), the problem is exactly the same:

```java
    private List<Application> findOtherRegisteredApplications() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private Map<Application, SwaggerParseResult> mapToDocs(List<Application> applications) {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    private RouteLocator buildRouteLocatorFrom(Map<Application, SwaggerParseResult> appsToDocs) {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes().build();
    }
```

Annotating the `RouteLocator` `@Bean` method with `@RefreshScope` leads to this exception:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at by.afinny.apigateway.ApiGatewayV2Application.main(ApiGatewayV2Application.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:482) ~[spring-cloud-context-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy107.getRoutes(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:208) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8773) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2752) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.lambda$onApplicationEvent$0(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2070) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.reset(RouteRefreshListener.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(RouteRefreshListener.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2753) ~[reactor-core-3.5.10.jar:3.5.10]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
```

It must have something to do with the dependency on `RouteLocatorProvider` because if I rewrite the `routeLocator()` method like so:

```java
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes().build();
    }
```

the application starts up successfully (that is, it *does* start up)

Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: please add buildRouteLocatorFrom method detail

Comment: @DingHao please see the edit. I omitted the methods for a good reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exception log

If the @RefreshScope annotation is not used, the custom routeLocator bean is not proxied. At this time, the RouteLocator instance returned by routeLocatorProvider.getRouteLocator() is actually null, that is, NullBean, because you initialize the routeLocator variable by listening to the CacheRefreshedEvent event, and this event It is sent by a scheduled task in DiscoveryClient (initScheduledTasks()), with a default delay of 30 seconds.

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "cachedCompositeRouteLocator")
    public RouteLocator cachedCompositeRouteLocator(List<RouteLocator> routeLocators) {
        return new CachingRouteLocator(new CompositeRouteLocator(Flux.fromIterable(routeLocators)));
    }
```

Therefore, the routeLocators obtained from the main RouteLocator actually only have a built-in RouteDefinitionRouteLocator (because NullBean will be filtered when injected), and there is no your customized routeLocator. There will be no problem when calling getRoutes() later. Of course, in this case, you can customize it. RouteLocator is equivalent to not being defined.

If the @RefreshScope annotation is used, the custom routeLocator will be proxied (but the real bean of the proxy is still NullBean). The routeLocators actually have two beans. Finally, when getRoutes() is executed, it will be executed on the NullBean instance, thus reporting object is not an instance of declaring class error

Comment: Thank you. But how do I fix it?

Comment: I added an extra invocation of `refreshRoutings()` before registering the listener in my `@PostConstruct`, and you know, the app did start up! It seems you were right